# Using combobox in rowediting using data binding

Tags: extjs, combobox, extjs5

I'm trying to create a basic test app where I use a grid, with row editing and letting the user change value of the field from a combo box. A very common use case (at least for me) and done many times in ExtJS 4.2 and earlier. However I'm trying to achieve this with less code, using the new ExtJS 5 data binding and associations.

I'm using two models (Person and Language) and each person should have one preferred language.
Person is simply id, name, languageid and language is id,languagename

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Person', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.person',

    fields: [
        {
            type: 'int',
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'name'
        },
        {
            name: 'languageid',
            reference: 'MyApp.model.Language'
        }
    ]
});

Ext.define('MyApp.model.Language', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    alias: 'model.language',

    fields: [
        {
            type: 'int',
            name: 'id'
        },
        {
            name: 'languagename'
        }
    ]
});

ViewModel:
Ext.define('MyApp.view.PersonsViewModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewModel',
    alias: 'viewmodel.persons',

    stores: {
        persons: {
            model: 'MyApp.model.Person',
            autoLoad:true
        },
        languages: {
            model: 'MyApp.model.Langugage',
            autoLoad:true
        }
    }

});

Grid (Part of larger View)
 {
            xtype: 'gridpanel',
            reference: 'grid',
            bind: {
                store: '{kamper}'
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    xtype: 'numbercolumn',
                    width: 35,
                    dataIndex: 'id',
                    text: 'Id'
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'gridcolumn',
                    width: 150,
                    dataIndex: 'langugageid',
                    text: 'Language',
                    editor: {
                        xtype: 'combobox',
                        lastQuery: '',
                        displayField: 'languagename',
                        valueField: 'id',
                        bind: {
                           selection: '{grid.selection.SomeRefToAssocStore.languagename}', /* 5.0.1 feature*/
                           value: '{grid.selection.profil}', /*should we even bind, since value is set from roweditor? */
                           store: '{languages}' /*directly to languages store or through grid store field association? */
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            listeners: {
                select: 'select'
            },
            features: [
                {
                    ftype: 'grouping',
                    groupHeaderTpl: [
                        'Avdeling: {name}'
                    ]
                }
            ],
            dockedItems: [
                {
                    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                    dock: 'bottom',
                    width: 360,
                    displayInfo: true,
                    bind: {
                        store: '{kamper}'
                    }
                }
            ],
            plugins: [
                {
                    ptype: 'rowediting'
                }
            ]
        }
```

I have some question in the code, but to sum up:

What it the best approach to set up a GUI like this?

How should I set the combo box binding?

Column data index is the id field, but I want to display the languagename value, is column renderer still the best approach?

Should the combo store be loaded or can I expect the association to take care of this (rest proxy removed from sample)

Should the combo store be linked to the languages store, or as some kind of sub-store of the field association?

I've been unable to find any complete examples with of this (combining rowedit, combo and binding)

Any pointers towards a "new" best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set renderer for editor column. Something like this:

```
editor: {
    xtype: 'combobox',
    store: store,
    editable: false,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name'
},
renderer: function(value) {
    var result = '';

    store.findBy(function(record) {
        if (record.getId() == value) {
            result = record.get('name');
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

[**Show on sencha fiddle**](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8ut)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing already.. In my case I'm sending the lookup value in the json from the server, so I can actually just to a return record.get('lookupvalue'). However I'm very interested to learn if the association is more than just data read in ExtJS 5

Comment: in a general way, for each data type - individual renderer and editor. editor: getEditor. getEditor: function (record, column) { switch(record.get('DataType')) { case something: Ext.create('needed component for this type'); } } and etc.